# setDragImage in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

Is there a way to create a snapshot of a draggable element in IE10, not the element itself but a dynamically created element that represents a draggable element? Basically, I am looking for the setDragImage method in the drag/drop IE 10 browser API and cannot find that in docs.

Answer (score 0):

`setDragImage` is not natively supported in IE10 (IE more generally), but there is this [polyfill](https://github.com/MihaiValentin/setDragImage-IE).

I've already used it and it does the job.